# Timer não executa ao alterar data do computador

Tags: java

Tenho esse timer simples que funciona normal. Porém quando altero a data do computador **Retroativa** o timer para de executar. Alguém sabe me explicar o porque??

Eu preciso saber se o usuário alterou a data do computador para bloquear lançamentos retroativos no sistema.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(
        new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Funcao.dataAtual("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: Qual é o pacote desta classe `Timer`? Pergunto isso porque já vi mais de uma classe com esse nome.

Comment: Você está usando `java.util.Timer`, correto? Não parece ser a `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: Oi, obrigada por responder. Estou usando os pacotes import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

Comment: Vale lembrar que mudar a data e a hora deveriam ser tarefas administrativas. Se for uma questão de evitar fraudes, não há nada que um usuário dedicado com poderes de administrador não vá conseguir burlar.

Answer (score 2):

Olhando no código-fonte da classe `java.util.Timer`, esses trechos de código podem ser localizados:

```java
public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period) {
    if (delay < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative delay.");
    if (period <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-positive period.");
    sched(task, System.currentTimeMillis()+delay, -period);
}
```

```java
private void sched(TimerTask task, long time, long period) {
    // [um monte de código] ...
            task.nextExecutionTime = time;
            task.period = period;
            task.state = TimerTask.SCHEDULED;
    // [mais um monte de código] ...
}
```

Na classe `TimerThread` (que acompanha a classe `Timer`, mas não é uma classe pública), é possível localizar-se o seguinte dentro do método `mainLoop()`:

```java
                    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    executionTime = task.nextExecutionTime;
                    if (taskFired = (executionTime<=currentTime)) {
```

Ou seja, o método `schedule` olha para o relógio (usando o método [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--)), calcula um tempo no futuro e chama o método `sched`, que utiliza o tempo calculado para definir quando a `task` será executada. No método `mainLoop()` ele pega a hora do relógio de novo (por meio do mesmo método) e verifica se já passou da hora marcada para rodar a `task`.

Isso significa que alterar a data do relógio interfere com a classe `java.util.Timer`. Alterar a data para trás irá adiar as execução das tarefas da classe `Timer`. Alterar a data para frente fará elas executarem antes da hora ou até mesmo imediatamente.

O ideal seria bolar uma solução com base no método [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--), o que significa abandonar a classe `java.util.Timer`. O método `nanoTime()` não sofre desse problema, pois ele conta quanto tempo passou desde algum ponto arbitrário de tempo definido quando a JVM é iniciada (pelo menos é isso o que diz a documentação, mas eu não confiaria nisso antes de testar).

Answer (score 1):

O `java.util.Timer` **é dependente da data e hora do sistema** operacional. Se acontecer de você voltar a hora, acredito eu que de acordo com este [bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6900441), ele vai simplesmente parar de funcionar.
Uma opção viável é usar algo como o `scheduleAtFixedRate` do `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecturor`, que, por ser baseado no `System.nanoTime`, não é baseado na data e hora do SO:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Q146466 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor sch = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) 
                Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5); // Pool de agendamento com 5 threads

        Runnable periodicTask = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // ...
            }
        };

        // Cria agendamento de tarefa para um intervalo de 5 segundos
        ScheduledFuture<?> periodicFuture = sch.scheduleAtFixedRate(periodicTask, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Maiores detalhes [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623755/stable-timer-independent-of-system-time) e [aqui](https://codelatte.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/49/).

Answer (score 0):

Obrigada pelo esclarecimento Victor T.  :D

consegui resolver com Thread.

O funcionamento fica igual do timer e ainda melhor pois não interfere no processo atual..  Segue exemplo

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {                
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("DataAtual: " + Funcao.dataAtual("dd/MM/yyyy"));
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MenuController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
```